# custom citation style for custom document

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I'm trying to have 2 separate "citation style" in my document, leveraging the customX existing document type (an extension would be to have a separate document type, but I don't want to play with the lbx file for the moment).

So I've used the type `customc` for my test. In the customc citation, there are no author and the citation should be "title, postnote" with an optional citation mode being "{title} {note}, postnote" if the note field is defined.

I'm having difficulties redefining the "customc:cite" for the document type customc. I thought it would be simply the same as `DeclareBibliographyDriver` bu I cannot find a way to make them work. How could I achieve this ? Here is what I get so far

[image]

And here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{book1,
author = {Author, Roberto B.},
title = {The Writing of History in Ancient Egypt during the First Millennium BC (ca. 1070-180 BC). Trends and Perspectives},
shorttitle = {A short title},
}
@customc{atf1,
    title       = {A title},
    note        = {= Un titre},
}
@customc{atf2,
    title       = {Another title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber,language=french]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\UndefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\newcommand{\no}{n\textsuperscript{o}\addnbthinspace}
\newcommand{\nos}{n\textsuperscript{os}\addnbthinspace}
\newcommand{\considerant}{consid.\addnbthinspace}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\newcommand{\ucites}{\parencites}

\DeclareFieldFormat[customc]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[customc]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[customc]{note}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[customc]{postnote}{\considerant #1}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customc}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \printfield{title}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}
}

\newbibmacro*{customc:cite}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
    \iffieldundef{note}{}{\printfield{note}}%
}

\begin{document}
a first test as demo \ucites[1]{book1}. a second text which also has some references \ucites[\nos 1, 2, 5]{book1}. 

Finally a test using the custom citation style \ucites[2.a \& 2.b]{atf1}[5.1]{atf2}. However the display should be "A title = Un titre, consid. 2.a \& 2.b".
\end{document}
```

Comment: The standard styles have no type-specific citation handling. All types are handled the same in citations. So you would have to modify the `cite` bibmacro. I could write an answer how that would work in the MWE, but I have the feeling that you may already have a highly modified `cite` bibmacro, in that case it might help if you added its definition to the MWE. In its current form `customc:cite` won't do anything.

Comment: Haha, based on my history, you're right. Bu actually, I was planning on using the authortitle version, with the potential goal to use the variation with the authoryear-icomp. So plain authortitle style :-)

Comment: Ah OK, with `authortitle` things should be not that horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the bibliography output the citation output is not type-dependent in the standard `biblatex` styles. That means that there is only one `cite` macro that controls the citation of all types and that there is no convenient macro like `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{<type>}` or `cite:<type>` to change the citation format of a particular type.

In this case the straightforward way just redefines the `cite` macro (as defined in `authortitlte.cbx`) as

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
     \ifentrytype{customc}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printfield{note}}
       {}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

This simply adds a test for the type `@customc` and prints the `note` field if we have a `@customc` entry.

---

If you are aiming to add more complicated definitions for other entry types as well, you may want to look at a different setup. The following allows you to define type-specific cite macros and falls back to the standard definition.

```
% save the "default" cite macro in cite:default.
% That means we can overwrite cite later
% and still use the old definition within the new one
\letbibmacro*{cite:default}{cite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifbibmacroundef{cite:\strfield{entrytype}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:default}}
    {\usebibmacro*{cite:\strfield{entrytype}}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:customc}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printfield{note}}
```

Comment: Works great and I like the approach with the default so much more than the approach I've seen in the swiss-legal files with nested if conditions. I just had an error from Overleaf on an undefined letbibmacro. I guess it's a question of version because copy-pasting the solution from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366435/wrapping-existing-bibmacro) works fine, thanks !

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is the reason for a single citation approach a question of unity of citation? I guess it would have been technically possible to have the same mechanism as for bibliography driver ?

Comment: @XaWin Indeed `\letbibmacro` is fairly new. The `biblatex` version on Overleaf does not know it yet. I guess there is only one unified citation macro for all types because usually all types have the same citation format. So normally there is little point in having type-specific citations.